# Why are titans killing humans?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Ok, huge spoilers for Attack on Titan in my questions.

> Does anyone have any ideas or theories about why humans are turning into armored and colossal titans, why those titans want to kill humans, and whether they are doing so intentionally?

Comment: The manga has some hints on why titans are killing humans. Nothing definitive, yet. Let's just say that the manga has shown very definitively what makes titans.

Comment: "*Does anyone have any ideas or theories*" - This is a site for asking for factual answers, not theoretical discussion. Can you rephrase this to not be opinion-based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok can't ask this question without expecting spoilers.

Per Armored/Sentient titans attacking in the show, it was revealed why they're currently attacking (in the manga). Which is basically to get back the controller from Eren/Historia.

As for why the war is even happening and what causes non-sentient Titans to attack, that has not yet been revealed.

**Side note a predominant current theory: It was mentioned the controller used to belong to armored titan's side of the war.  If that is true, non-sentient titans attacking humans on sight maybe a command from previous controllers instead of biological need. Also augmented by instances where titans ignored humans and attacked other titans.